# Get features by querying shapefile

Tags: python, sql, gis, qgis, osgeo

I have a shapefile and I would like to query features that are inside of the geometry (Polygon) by executing SQL script. I am using Python osgeo library for running the queries:

```
shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open(file)
layer = shapefile.GetLayer()
driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
layer = shapefile.GetLayer()
test = shapefile.ExecuteSQL('select * from "%s"' % layer.GetName())
```

However, I have no idea how to alter this select statement to select items that are inside of the polygon (i.e. POLYGON(12.578608968 55.6344916225, 12.578625747 55.6344383472, 12.5791438324 55.633937277, 12.5792915832 55.6339468684, 12.5793944291 55.6340760336, 12.578608968 55.6344916225)). My intuition say that it would be someting like:

```
select * from layer
where geometry in Polygon(.....)
```

I can do that using GUI in QuantumGIS desktop, so it must be possible to query features in SQL as well, though I cannot find any resources online.

Any ideas for this?

Comment: Qgis console(python) will do?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I dont want to use Qgis. What I have is stand-alone Python application where I want to query shapefile.

Comment: Do you want to select a polygon inside another? Then you need two polygon or separate geometry? e.g. school inside county?

Comment: I would like to select points (features from shapefile) that are in polygon

Comment: OK then example will be How many school fall inside X county?

Comment: Very close. However, instead specifying country as a property, I need to specify country as a polygon and instead of querying school count, I need list of schools in a polygon

Comment: A bit obscure can you post dummy data for both layer?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for this to be answered properly. You should post the schemas of the relevant layers and which fields you want to return. Also, do you want a pure database solution, or a pure python solution (either is possible)? You also may get better help on [the gis stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have found a solution by using SetSpatialFilter function on a layer. Thank you for your comments though

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Intersects](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723234109/http://www.gdal.org:80/classOGRGeometry.html#aadb34b556c52aef3e93f03cf65d3f4bc) method from GDAL is the one you need, which determines if two geometries intersect each other by comparing it like:

```
geomA.Intersects(geomB)
```

With this method, you could save the Polygon you wish to compare into a geometry, and then iterate the features in your shapefile comparing each one to see if it intersects your desired polygon (with `GetNextFeature()`, or by doing some Query and then iterating the result set).